# How to create and maintain a persistent socket connection in Android WiFiDirect?

Tags: java, android, sockets

I'm using WiFiDirect to connect two phones and transfer images between them. I'm able to connect the devices and transfer 1 image from client to server. I'm failing when I try to transfer more than 1 image.

I use onConnectionInfoAvailable method to launch my server and client threads.

```
@Override
public void onConnectionInfoAvailable(WifiP2pInfo info) {
    Log.i(TAG, "GO address " + info.groupOwnerAddress.getHostAddress() + " isGroupOwner " + info.isGroupOwner);
    this.info = info;
    if (info.groupFormed && info.isGroupOwner) {
        ServerRunnable serverRunnable = new ServerRunnable(imageToBeSet);
        Thread serverThread = new Thread(serverRunnable);
        serverThread.start();
    } else {
        //Start client thread and transfer image.
    }
```

ServerRunnable :

```
public class ServerRunnable implements Runnable {
    public void run() {
        try {

            ServerSocket serverSocket = new ServerSocket(PORT);
            Socket clientSocket = serverSocket.accept();

            while (connected) {
                try {

                    InputStream inputStream = clientSocket.getInputStream();
                    final byte[] result = streamToByteArray(inputStream);
                    MainActivity.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(result, 0, result.length);
                            clientImage.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
                        }
                    });
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    //Handle exception
                }
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            //Handle exception
        }
    }
}
```

ClientRunnable :

```
public class ClientRunnable implements Runnable {
    public void run() {
        try {
            Log.d("ClientActivity", "C: Connecting...");
            Thread.sleep(2000l);
            socket.bind(null);
            socket.connect(new InetSocketAddress(host, PORT), 5000);

            while (connected) {
                if(outputStream == null) {
                    try {
                        outputStream = socket.getOutputStream();
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        // Handle exception
                    }
                }
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
             // Handle exception
        }
    }
    public void write(byte[] bytes) {
        try {
            outputStream.write(bytes, 0, bytes.length);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

The above write method does not work. The OutputStream is connected to the server socket when I debug I see the info about me server (ip address and post number). Not sure why the write is not being read by my server. The socket shows as connected too.

The first transfer works fine. I have a layout with Previous and Next buttons. When the button is pressed, I want to read the image byte array and transfer that. I'm unable to do this part.

If anyone knows how I can create and maintain a persistent socket connection, or any other way to transfer multiple images from client to server using WiFiDirect please let me know. I based this off of the WiFiDirectDemo in Android SDK samples.

Thanks,

Akash

P.S.: I've also looked at the WiFiP2PDemo which uses a WifiP2pDnsSdService. I'm currently trying to understand how they are keeping the sockets open for continuous chat.

Comment: We need to see much more context (i.e. code).

Comment: At the first glance, you seem to create one thread to transfer one image. And you do this only when (new) connection info is available. So the thread runs, transfers, terminates. Either create a new thread each time an image should be transferred (and not only when connection info becomes available), or use some possibly minimalistic form of inter-thread communication to tell one thread which images to transfer before terminating.

Comment: @HannoBinder Yes, that's correct. I create a server thread and a client thread when I get connection info. I then create an InputStream and an OutputStream to exchange data using the sockets created. So my understanding (correct me if I'm wrong, I have been working on sockets for only a week) is as long as my streams are open and sockets are connected, I should be able to transfer data between them with the "outputStream.write" method. My earlier solution was using an AsyncTask to transfer image from the client (new task for each image) and I still wasn't able to transfer more than 1 image.